# Is this why any column in matrix A is in set ColA?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a matrix $A$. Because the set Col $A$ is defined as the Span of the columns of $A$, then
$$
\mathbf{a_n} = 0\cdot\mathbf{a_1} + 0\cdot\mathbf{a_2} + \cdots 1\cdot \mathbf{a_n} + \cdots 0\cdot\mathbf{a_p} 
$$
implies $\mathbf{a_n}$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$ and thus in Col $A$.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks.

Comment: More generally, this is why any vector belongs to its span. (The whole purpose of the span of a set of vectors is to get the smallest linear space *containing* the original vectors.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a matrix $A$. Because the set Col $A$ is defined as the Span of the columns of $A$, then
$$
\mathbf{a_n} = 0\cdot\mathbf{a_1} + 0\cdot\mathbf{a_2} + \cdots 1\cdot \mathbf{a_n} + \cdots 0\cdot\mathbf{a_p} 
$$
implies $\mathbf{a_n}$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$ and thus in Col $A$.